# ASP.net button has to be clicked twice for a jquery function call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

**What I need:** I have the working code that I need to change and update. I have a modal control (Just like a pop up box) that gets called on a button click. Now, I need to calculate something in vb.net code and then make a decision to call it. (pop up box appears)

**Problem:** It gets called, but I have to click twice on my button.  The call only happens when the CssClass is set as follows: `CssClass="osx ImageButton100"`

**Background:** Modal control that I am using: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

**Changes that were made:**

```
Before:

 <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Text="Preview Order" CssClass="osx ImageButton100"        />
```

Now:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Text="Preview Order"   />
  btnCheckOut.CssClass = "osx ImageButton100"
```

Complete code:

http://forums.asp.net/post/5367139.aspx

Comment: Can you call the modal from JavaScript? That would be a lot easier.

Comment: Also, I know this is what your using, but i would recommend twitter bootstrap modal. Its easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

In your code-behind, what is `Utils.MessageBox`? (Called from your button-click event handler).

Anyway, it looks to me like your code is behaving as designed. Steps:

1. User clicks button.
2. Post-back occurs, server-side code sets properties on button that configure it to show a pop-up.
3. Page response sent back to client.
4. User clicks button a second time, and now it shows a modal (because its class is configured).

You're breaking the flow of client-side code by issuing a postback (the button click is calling a server-side event handler). There's a few options of how to carry on the flow:

1. Continue to use a postback, but have the server-side code register a "startup" script to execute on the javascript page load event. This can be kind of clumsy though, especially if the user refreshes the page.
2. Have your button-click perform a callback instead of a postback. There's a few different ways you can go about that, I'd recommend *not* using the WebForms `UpdatePanel` approach though.
3. Move all of this logic client-side.

Given how simple your button-click event handler is, I'd recommend the third option. So forget about a server-side event handler for `btnCheckOut`. Start out with the button classes already set to `osx ImageButton100`. Then change your javascript click handler to something more like:

```
$("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     

    var lineCount = $("#txtApprovalNotes").val()
                        .match(/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/gi).length;

    if (lineCount > 20) {
        alert("Approval notes has a limit of 20 lines.";
    } else {
        $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
            overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
            containerId: 'osx-container',
            closeHTML: '<div class="close">
   <a href="#" class="simplemodal-close" style="font-size:150%;">x</a></div>',
            minHeight:80,
            opacity:65, 
            position:['0',],
            overlayClose:true,
            onOpen:OSX.open,
            onClose:OSX.close,
            appendTo:'form'
        });
    }
});
```

Not only will this make maintaining the flow of logic simpler, but it will cut a postback out of the equation and make things more responsive in the browser.